# How to get the size of the camera view, before taking a picture, using imagepicker

Tags: ios, camera

First of all, let me know if this is a duplicate so I can delete it. I couldn't find anything similar but I may be searching with the wrong keywords.

Here's my issue: If you use the imagepicker to start the camera to take a picture, you get the default "live" view of what the camera sees, and you have the default shutter button and cancel button, along with extra camera buttons at the top. So far no issues with that.

What I want to know is what the size is of this "live view" before I take a picture. I have the size of the image and all of that, but in order to create a properly formatted overlay just over the "live view" I need to know where the live view starts and where it ends.

Any idea how to get the size of this view?

Let me know if you need some of my existing code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourImagePicker.view.frame.size.width
```

and

```
yourImagePicker.view.frame.size.height
```

Comment: I forgot to try it with the .view param. Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, this gives me the size of the entire view, not just the imagePicker "inside view" size

Comment: Might want to expand this answer to explain why it's the correct answer.